# Binding a button to both a function and close event wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button, binding, command

I have a `UserControl` which is binded to a `ViewModel` class.

I also have a class which contains a `Command` for closing a window.

In my `UserControl` I have two buttons: **Save** and **Cancel**.

My **Cancel** button is binded to the `CloseWindow Command` and when I click it, the `UserControl` is indeed closing.

I bound my **Save** button to a function in the `ViewModel`, there I wish to perform an actual save and only then close the `UserControl`. I've tried several things but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

**The CloseWindow Command:**

```
public static readonly ICommand CloseWindow = new RelayCommand(currentCommand => ((Window)currentCommand).Close());
```

**The code in my xaml:**

```
        <Button x:Name="Cancel" Height="25" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="DarkRed" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" Command="{x:Static Auxiliary_Resources:CommonCommands.CloseWindow}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="Ok" Height="25" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="DarkRed" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Save" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding CreateContactCommand}"/>
```

**The function in the ViewModel:**

```
        private void CreateContact(object parameter)
        {
           if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_contactToAdd.FirstName)) &&
               (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_contactToAdd.LastName)) &&
               (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_contactToAdd.BankName)) &&
               (m_contactToAdd.AccountNumber != null & (m_contactToAdd.AccountNumber != 0)))
              {
                    m_contactToAdd = Contact.CreateContact(m_contactToAdd.FirstName, m_contactToAdd.LastName,m_contactToAdd.BankName, m_contactToAdd.AccountNumber);
                    DbHandler.AddContact(m_contactToAdd);
              }

           CommonCommands.CloseWindow.Execute(null);
       }
```

This of course crashes because I'm sending `null` instead of the window.

Is there a way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply send the window as the `CommandParameter`, as you have already done for your `CloseCommand`.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

And send it to the `Execute` method.

```
CommonCommands.CloseWindow.Execute(parameter);
```